# Swift / Firebase: Is there a way to check for an update in the Firebase Database in the background of an app?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to create a game with Firebase, and I wanted to run a function when the current user gets a friend request in the real-time database. The function, for example, will show the friend request under a friend request table. Is there any way, perhaps in the App Delegate or elsewhere, where I can check for a friend request (an update in the Firebase Database) for certain intervals when the app is open (no matter which View Controller is shown)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Firebase Realtime Database client use a (Web) Socket to keep a connection with the servers. This is very efficient, but keeping the radio chip active uses significant power. For this reason the OS will typically close such connections when the application isn't actively being used.

To reliably deliver messages when the application isn't actively being used, consider using Firebase Cloud Messaging, which (on iOS) uses APNS for delivering the messages. This is a more power efficient way of delivering messages, so is typically allowed more leniently by the operating system.

Comment: Thank you! I will look into Firebase Cloud Messaging.